# Django returning blank page on POST

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is almost certainly a newbie error but I can't work out what's wrong. I've read through the other similar questions on here but non seem to be quite the same.

I have a simple form which posts data but I always get a completely blank response.

Here's the code:

url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('shotgun.views',
    # shotgun App URL patterns
    url(r'^$', ControlPanelView.as_view(), name='index'),
)
```

form.py

```
class ProjectAssignmentForm(forms.Form):

    projects = MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, user_projs, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectAssignmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["projects"].choices = tuple([(item.name, item.name) for item in SGProject.objects.all() if item.name != "Template Project"])
        self.fields["projects"].initial = user_projs
```

view.py

```
class ControlPanelView(SLBaseView):

    template_name = "shotgun/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ControlPanelView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        sg_user = SGCustomNonProjectEntity01.objects.filter(code=self.request.user.get_full_name())[0]
        projs = SGProject.objects.filter(Q(entities__entity_id=sg_user.id), Q(entities__type="CustomNonProjectEntity01"))

        context["assigned_projs"] = projs

        if self.request.method == "POST":
            form = ProjectAssignmentForm(projs, self.request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                 # update user projects logic
        else:
            form = ProjectAssignmentForm(projs)

        context["pas_form"] = form

        return context
```

template.html

```
<div class="full_width" >
    <h4 class="no_pad" >{{ user.first_name|upper }}'S CONTROL PANEL</h4>
</div>

<div class="full_width top_tab">
    <div class="border border_pad">
    <h6>PROJECTS YOU ARE ASSIGNED TO</h6>
    {% if assigned_projs %}
        <form action="/intranet/shotgun/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="border_pad">
                {{ pas_form.projects.errors }}
                {{ pas_form.projects }}
                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </div>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        <p>You are not assigned to any projects.</p>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the csrf middleware enabled in my settings.py

The behaviour I would expect from all this would be:

Unbound form - display the page with pre-populated data

Bound invalid - display the page with selected data

Bound valid - display the page with updated data

The unbound data page displays as expected but as soon as the post request is created by clicking the Update button on the form the a blank page is displayed. I tried throwing an exception after the `if self.request.method == "POST"` statement but the code doesn't seem to get this far. I'm really not sure what's going on.

Comment: Daniel, Were you able to get this working? I know it's been a while since you posted but i'm having the same error and unfortunately Dan's solution below doesn't seem to be the issue. I am receiving the correct django error page for other errors.

Answer (score -1):

There is a syntax error in your views.py file.

```
    if self.request.method == "POST":
    form = ProjectAssignmentForm(projs, self.request.POST)
```

should be

```
    if self.request.method == "POST":
        form = ProjectAssignmentForm(projs, self.request.POST)
```

Do you have debugging turned off? That would explain why you're not getting any output. Because there is a fatal error django would print an error report, but if debugging is off it will email the error report to the admin listed in settings.py instead.

Check that in settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
```